# $\mathcal{\underline{J}}(\underline{r},t)=\rho(\underline{r},t) \underline{v}(\underline{r},t)$ from Maxwell equations

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations

In classical EM theory one can use the following equations as independent:

$$\nabla \times \mathcal{\underline{E}}(\underline{r},t)=-\frac{\partial \mathcal{\underline{B}}(\underline{r},t)}{\partial t}$$

$$\nabla \times \mathcal{\underline{H}}(\underline{r},t)=\frac{\partial \mathcal{\underline{D}}(\underline{r},t)}{\partial t}+\mathcal{\underline{J}}(\underline{r},t)$$

$$\nabla \cdot \mathcal{\underline{J}}(\underline{r},t)=-\frac{\partial \rho(\underline{r},t)}{\partial t}$$

which are 7 equations in 16 unknowns.
Adding to these the medium equations (suppose: linear, stationary, homogeneous, isotropic, non-dispersive):

$$\mathcal{\underline{D}}(\underline{r},t)=\epsilon\mathcal{\underline{E}}(\underline{r},t)$$
$$\mathcal{\underline{B}}(\underline{r},t)=\mu\mathcal{\underline{H}}(\underline{r},t)$$
$$\mathcal{\underline{J}}(\underline{r},t)=\sigma\mathcal{\underline{E}}(\underline{r},t)$$

we have now 16 equations in 16 unknowns and, in theory, the electromagnetic problem is solved.

So, why introducing the equation $\mathcal{\underline{J}}(\underline{r},t)=\rho(\underline{r},t) \underline{v}(\underline{r},t)$?
Is it possible to derive it from the 16 equations-complete system listed before?

Comment: There are a couple of things that I notice are missing form your discussion. Firstly you do not metion the Lorentz force law, or the energy of a charge in a potential, or the energy of a field distribution, or some other equivelant condition which tells charges how to move in responce to a field. This matters because the idea with the equation $\mathcal{J} = \rho v$ is that we ultimately want to make contact with some microscopic model that can tell us $v$ in terms of the dynamics of charges in the field.

Comment: The second thing that is missing is that you have a system of differential equations *and have at no point discussed the boundry conditions*. You cannot even begin to discuse whether you have enough information for a unique solution to your system without them!

Comment: Even with the Lorentz force included to describe the interaction between the field and the particle, how to formally justify the relation between current and charge?
Lorentz force is "experimental" as the Maxwell equation.
Is the relation $\mathcal{\underline{J}}(\underline{r},v)=\rho(\underline{r},v) v(\underline{r},v)$ also?